# Is the accepted alternative to inheritance in puppet nodes class inclusion?

Tags: class, inheritance, include, puppet

After reading multiple style guides and trying to not use inheritance in my node definitions ([as suggested by puppet labs](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_node_definitions.html#inheritance)), I would like to know what the common way of including classes in puppet without using inheritance.

I have been trying the following with my node definitions, but it does not seem to work:

```
# in module 'baseclass'
# baseclass.pp
class baseclass {
  include xclass
  include yclass
  include zclass
}

# servernode01.pp
node 'servernode01' {
  include baseclass
}
```

where `xclass`, `yclass` and `zclass` are funcitonal puppet classes and including them in the node `servernode01` produces the desired state (i.e. the resources are applied to the node).

## My question(s) are:

1. Is including classes in classes a good alternative to inheritance?
2. Are there some issues in the methodology I am using as an alternative to inheritance?

I ask my second question since it seems the nodes that include `baseclass` do not receive the resources defined in `xclass`, `yclass` and `zclass`.

My ultimate goal is to have a base class that will implement the minimum requirements which I specify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. yes, composition is better than inheritance in Puppet
2. your example should work fine

An alternative to `include baseclass` is `class { 'baseclass': }`. You need the latter if you want to use parameters, and also have into account that you can use `include` multiple times but not the `class` syntax, as puppet will complain with duplicate class definition.

Comment: Good points all. It is all quite formalized in the de facto standard of Craig Dunn's [roles and profiles pattern](http://www.craigdunn.org/2012/05/239/).

Answer (score 3):

The official puppet docs state clearly that inheritance should be used only really "sparingly". They actually name exactly two situations where this should happen:

- when you want to overwrite a parmeter of a resource defined in the parent class
- when you want to inherit from a parameters class for standard parameter values

see http://bit.ly/1r1RO0K

So yes, this is clearly better, even with official blessing :)